# Error Glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, glassfish-4, servlet-3.0

I have a project in java, with servlets 3.1, which uses Ajax in different parts of the application. It has several multipart forms. Every few hours jumping the following error:

```
 java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleRead(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:90)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleRead(TransportFilter.java:173)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.read(DefaultFilterChain.java:351)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.read(FilterChainContext.java:695)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.blockingRead(InputBuffer.java:1119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.io.ServerInputBuffer.blockingRead(ServerInputBuffer.java:95)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.fill(InputBuffer.java:1143)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:353)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:267)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977)
at org.apache.catalina.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:888)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.fileupload.Streams.copy(Streams.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.fileupload.Streams.copy(Streams.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.fileupload.Multipart.initParts(Multipart.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.fileupload.Multipart.getPart(Multipart.java:190)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getPart(Request.java:4546)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getPart(RequestFacade.java:1095)
at controller.FileUploadServletPathEasyRead.doPost(FileUploadServletPathEasyRead.java:93)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:126)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:75)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractReader.read(AbstractReader.java:72)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleRead(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:77)
... 52 more]]
```

The line generates the exception in the servlet is: **Part filePart = request.getPart("files[]");**

**I have the following code in Ajax javascript:**

```js
<script>
$(function () {
                            $('#fileuploadpatheasyread<%=p.getIdPath()%>').fileupload({
                                dataType: 'json',
                                timeout: 50000,
                                add: function (e, data) {
                                    var goUpload = true;
                                    var uploadFile = data.files[0];
                                    if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(uploadFile.name)) {
                                        alert('The extension of the image file is not correct');
                                        goUpload = false;
                                    }
                                    if (uploadFile.size > 2097152) { // 2mb
                                        alert('Please upload a smaller image, max size is 2 MB');
                                        goUpload = false;
                                    }
                                    if (goUpload == true) {
                                        data.submit();
                                    }
                                },
                                done: function (e, data) {
                                    $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                                         
                                    }); 
                                },
                                fail: function (e, data) {
                                    alert("Error")
                                },
                                progressall: function (e, data) {
                                       
                                },
                               

                                dropZone: $('#dropzone<%=p.getIdPath()%>')
                            }).bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {     
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We are having similar problems.